# Number of ways to partition an array into two parts with same count of unique elements

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, partitioning, counting

I have task to find number of ways to partition an array on two parts where both parts have same size and have same number of unique elements. For example:

Array: `[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]`

There are 8 possible ways:

```
(1, 2, 4, 4, 4) - (2, 3, 3, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 3, 4, 4) - (2, 2, 3, 4, 4)
(1, 3, 4, 4, 4) - (2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
(1, 4, 4, 4, 4) - (2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
(2, 2, 3, 3, 3) - (1, 4, 4, 4, 4)
(2, 2, 3, 3, 4) - (1, 3, 4, 4, 4)
(2, 2, 3, 4, 4) - (1, 3, 3, 4, 4)
(2, 3, 3, 3, 4) - (1, 2, 4, 4, 4)
```

I wrote recursive solution but it is slow, looks like it has exponential time complexity. I think exists better approach to solve this problem, probably DP or something else. Could you help to find something better?

Comment: Dynamic programming definitely works. Can you just add caching to your recursive solution to get a top down DP approach?

Comment: I'm assuming your example shows what you want, but to confirm, you consider (1, 2, 4, 4, 4) - (2, 3, 3, 3, 4) to be different from (2, 3, 3, 3, 4) - (1, 2, 4, 4, 4)?

Comment: Please share the recursive solution you wrote.

Comment: @Dave actually it is not important, my goal to find number of ways, so for case in example total cases is 252, and ways to get same number of unique elements in both parts is 78. So I can calculate number only for first 4 cases and multiply on 2 because rest are complement to first

Comment: @Nikitka Well, in this case sure, but you'll have symmetric cases too. E.g., (1,2)-(1,2). But point taken; you can handle those separately in linear time so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The follow approach is simple-minded from an algorithmic complexity
standpoint, but attempts to be very efficient per operation.

### Algorithm

The basic idea is to use a bitmap with the same cardinaltiy as the
data to keep track of the paritionings. The set bits correspond to the
elements in the left partition and the zero bits to the elements in
the right partition. If there are `N` data elements, the parition
bitmap will always have `N/2` bits set (and cleared) and can be
incremented to the next lexicographic permutation very efficiently.

In this incarnation, there will be permutations that result in
duplicate partitions because of duplicates in the data elements. I
think this duplication can be eliminated at the cost of some
additional bookkeeping, which should substantially increase
performance, but I have not impemented that yet. The current code
simply keeps track of all the results and then eliminates the
duplicates in the last step.

### Code

The following code can also be found on
[GitHub](https://github.com:cpp-core/so) in the `76185299` directory.

```cpp
#include "core/util/tool.h"
#include "core/util/random.h"

/// Return the lexicographically next bit permutation with the same
/// number of bits set as `r`.
template<std::unsigned_integral T>
auto next_permutation_n(T n) {
    auto m = n bitor (n - 1);
    return (m + 1) bitor (((~m bitand -~m) - 1) >> (std::countr_zero(n) + 1));
}

/// Return the number of distinct subsets of size `k` given a set of
/// size `n` (informally, n choose k).
template<std::integral T>
auto n_choose_k(T n, T k) {
    if (k == 0) return T{1};
    if (k > n / 2) k = n - k;

    T r{1};
    for (auto i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
        r *= n - i + 1;
        r /= i;
    }
    return r;
}

using Element = uint;
using Elements = std::vector<Element>;
using PartitionMask = uint64_t;

// Return the number of unique elements in in the selected partition
// of `data`, which must be in sorted order.
auto count_unique(const Elements& data, PartitionMask mask) {
    std::optional<Element> last;
    int idx{std::countr_zero(mask)};
    size_t n{};
    while (mask) {
        auto elem = data[idx];
        if (not last or (elem != *last)) {
            ++n;
            last = elem;
        }
        mask >>= std::countr_zero(mask) + 1;
        idx += std::countr_zero(mask) + 1;
    }
    return n;
}

void add_partition(Elements& part, const Elements& data, PartitionMask mask) {
    int idx{std::countr_zero(mask)};
    while (mask) {
        part.push_back(data[idx]);
        mask >>= std::countr_zero(mask) + 1;
        idx += std::countr_zero(mask) + 1;
    }
}

// Return true if the two partitions select the same element values.
bool same(const Elements& data, PartitionMask a, PartitionMask b) {
    int idx{std::countr_zero(a)}, jdx{std::countr_zero(b)};
    while (a and b) {
        if (data[idx] != data[jdx])
            return false;
        a >>= std::countr_zero(a) + 1;
        b >>= std::countr_zero(b) + 1;
        idx += std::countr_zero(a);
        jdx += std::countr_zero(b);
    }
    return true;
}

int tool_main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    // Start with sorted elements.
    std::vector<unsigned int> data = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4 };
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), std::less{});

    // There must be an even number of elements for the left and right
    // subsets to be of equal size.
    auto n = data.size();
    if (n == 0 or n bitand 1)
        return 0;

    // Construct a bit-mask where the one bits mark the left subset of
    // elements and the zero bits mark the right subset of
    // elements. Start with the lower half of the bits set.
    auto partition = (1ull << (n / 2)) - 1;

    // One past the last partition to consider.
    auto end_partition = 1ull << n;

    // These are the only bits that count.
    auto global_mask = end_partition - 1;

    std::vector<std::vector<uint>> results;

    // Iterate over all the partitionings.
    while (partition < end_partition) {
        if (count_unique(data, partition) == count_unique(data, ~partition bitand global_mask)) {
            results.push_back({});
            add_partition(results.back(), data, partition);
            add_partition(results.back(), data, ~partition bitand global_mask);
        }
        partition = next_permutation_n(partition);
    }

    std::sort(results.begin(), results.end());
    auto last = std::unique(results.begin(), results.end());
    results.erase(last, results.end());

    for (const auto& r : results) {
        cout << "[ ";
        for (auto i = 0; i < r.size() / 2; ++i)
            cout << r[i] << " ";
        cout << "] - [ ";
        for (auto i = r.size() / 2; i < r.size(); ++i)
            cout << r[i] << " ";
        cout << "]" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Results

```
$ partition
[ 1 2 4 4 4 ] - [ 2 3 3 3 4 ]
[ 1 3 3 4 4 ] - [ 2 2 3 4 4 ]
[ 1 3 4 4 4 ] - [ 2 2 3 3 4 ]
[ 1 4 4 4 4 ] - [ 2 2 3 3 3 ]
[ 2 2 3 3 3 ] - [ 1 4 4 4 4 ]
[ 2 2 3 3 4 ] - [ 1 3 4 4 4 ]
[ 2 2 3 4 4 ] - [ 1 3 3 4 4 ]
[ 2 3 3 3 4 ] - [ 1 2 4 4 4 ]
```

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't looks like solution I'm looking for, it doesn't have much better performance than recursive solution of mine, also it has huge memory consumption